# How is corruption measured?

Tags: corruption, statistics

The [2012 Corruption Perceptions Index](http://www.transparency.org/cpi2012/results) was just published and according to it, Greece has the dubious honour of being the [most corrupted member of the European Union](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business-20605869).

Naturally this stung a bit, and I looked at the [relevant Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corruption_Perceptions_Index) for an explanation of the methods used in the index. It didn't help much, most of the references aren't publicly available and those that are don't really explain much. The [criticism section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corruption_Perceptions_Index#Criticism) was a bit more revealing about CPI's methodology, but I don't know how substantiated those criticisms are.

Could someone explain to me in layman's terms how corruption is measured?

Comment: ...and I've just realized the corruption tag didn't exist before this question. I guess it's appropriate that a Greek created it ;P

Comment: Super-difficult to measure that, because as corruption increases you get more corruption court cases and media coverage, but if it increases some more, you get _less_ of those. Perception of corruption is probably also a "non-monotone function" of the level of corruption. Perhaps you actually can't?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[This 2010 article at nobribe.org](http://www.nobribe.org/how-to-measure-corruption) claims

> Measurement of Corruption thus far, has been limited to measuring perception of Corruption [...] Various approaches to measure Corruption directly may be suggested based on how other intractable quantities are measured.  One such model to measure petty Corruption based on Inflation, is discussed [...].

(The latter contains a link that should probably point to an article entitled ["Obtaining a Driver's License in India: An Experimental Approach to Studying Corruption"](http://qje.oxfordjournals.org/content/122/4/1639.abstract).)

As for the methodology of Corruptions Perception Index, a little digging on the Transparency International website leads to a ["data package"](http://files.transparency.org/content/download/533/2213/file/2012_CPI_DataPackage.zip) including a "Source description" pdf mentioning 13 different studies as source, some focussed on corruption, some not, often relying on a limited number of "experts" (e.g. 2 per country for study 3, 4200 responding "business executives", apprently in total, for study 7) to "assess" (not: "measure") a question, sometimes longer and detailed, sometimes shorter (e.g. “Bribing and corruption: Exist or do not exist”) on a given scale.