# Nationally-mandated term limits for mayors?

Tags: local-government, election-requirements

Are there any *countries* that impose **term limits for mayors**? Are there any good *arguments* in favour of such a rule? I could only find some links about the [ambiguous situation in Portugal](http://portugalfromtheinside.wordpress.com/2013/02/18/portugals-dinosaur-mayors-may-avoid-extinction/),

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes,** but not many.

Wikipedia has a [nice chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_political_term_limits) for comparing term limits across countries, but I can't say how all-inclusive it is. I *can* say that it at least gives a reference for Taiwan, which sets term limits for mayors at two consecutive four-year terms. This is found in Articles 55/56/57 of the [Local Government Act](http://law.moj.gov.tw/Eng/LawClass/LawAll.aspx?PCode=A0040003), with separate sections for special municipalities, county/city, and township/city governments:

> The county/city governments shall have a magistrate/mayor, who shall represent the county/city in external affairs and administer affairs of the county/city. The magistrate shall likewise oversee the self-government of townships/cities under its jurisdiction. The magistrate/mayor shall be popularly elected to a term of four years and may be re-elected to a second term.

Wikipedia also lists The Phillipines as having terms limits of 3 three-year terms for "all other local government officials," which I assume includes mayors. Unfortunately I can't find that reference.

Arguments for/against mayoral term limits are [largely the same](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/396/4802) as they are for other positions to me.

Comment: Well, having the central government mandate limits for local election seems a bit of a paradox, or at least runs counter to the spirit of decentralization...

Comment: A bit counter, but nations set rules for what local governments can/can't do with elections all the time. Term limits specifically might be unusual, but for election laws in general you could use something as simple as civil rights laws mandated nationally in many countries.